# How do you access data from axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

Here's what I have

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'
import PokemonCard from './components/PokemonCard'

const BASE_URL = 'https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards'

const App = () => {

const [image,setImage] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
axios.get(`${BASE_URL}`)
.then(function (response) {
  setImage(response.data)
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
})
},[])
```

This works...

```
console.log(image) // displays an ARRAY OF OBJECTS
```

This is expected to work, but doesn't...

```
console.log(image[0].name)
```

The reason the latter console.log is expected to work is because `image` is definitely an array of objects. I know that for a fact. So, [0] would pick out the first array, you would think And `name` is the name of the key value pair. So, the broken piece of this `console.log(image[0].name)` should pick out the value of the name of the first array in the image array of objects.

I would appreciate your help trying to figure out why this hasn't been working for the last 8 hours of searching the globe for an answer that apparently Google doesn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const [image,setImage] = useState([])` initializes the state as an empty array. And the `useEffect` hook will run after the component has been mounted for the first time. Which means the first time the component renders with state value of `image` still being an empty array(`[]`), so when you try to access `image[0].name` because `image[0]` in `undefined` it produces the error.

Because the array `image` is populated by the asynchronous API call after the component has mounted for the first time, if you want to log `image[0].name` the simplest way is to check for the `length` of the array then log the name of the first element. The same check has to be done if you want to pass `image[0].name` as a prop.

For example,

```js
if (image.length) {
  console.log(image[0].name) // expected result will be logged
}

// if you want to pass the value of image[0].name as a prop
return (
  <div>
   {
    image.length && <SomeComponent imgName={image[0].name}/>
   }
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Axios call and the `setState` hook are asynchronous you need to check if `image` has already been set, something like this

```js
if(image && image.length > 0) console.log(image[0].name)
```